# 2D Java Networked Game Coordinate Updating

Tags: java

I'm currently developing a networked 2D MMO-style game in which several thin clients (ran in an applet) are able to connect to a server and well, do MMO-style "things"!

Some more background on the game: First of all, I'm using UDP to make this possible. There is a scrolling background whenever a user is moving up/down/left/right constantly, and each client has its own 2D avatar always centered in their screen.

My problem I've been facing these last three or so days is this: I guess I don't understand the math really behind the process of updating the X,Y positions for each client, for all of the clients, because right now whenever a new client is connected, the first client that was running actually moves the latter client whenever it is "WSAD-ing".

I guess I was hoping for some insight as to how I should approach this, with a scrolling background, and the individual client is always in the middle of the screen but updating with other clients moving around the world.

Comment: I don't think you should use UDP for something like this.  UDP is good for an environment where a dropped packet means you should forget it and move to the next one.  In a game, if one player moves and the other player doesn't get it, what if he doesn't move again for a while?  The clients will be out of synch.  You don't want to solve this problem by repeatedly sending the location even when it hasn't changed.  This will cause more traffic and more dropped packets.  I would highly suggest you switch to TCP before you get too far into the code.

Comment: Perhaps you will find better answers for this question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state, you need to place each user in the middle, they don't need to move around.

You work out the relative location of other users compared with the user which is playing. If they are too far away, you don't draw them at all.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to do with some central server that would store locations for all objects using its own, main reference coordinate system. A client should register with this server when it starts and the server could periodically check if the clients are still alive/online.